# replicate function code in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I define replicate function (eventhough haskell have it) using **list** **comprehension** only? The signature should be `replicate':: Int -> a -> [a]`

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know of any way to generate `n` elements of something simply in Haskell?

Comment: I'll give you a [hint](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#texas-ranges).

Comment: [x| x <- [1..n]]. The replicate' must do what replicate function in haskell does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replicate' n x = [x|_ <- [1..n]]
```